# How to use parameters in a ee.String?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have 2 names extracted from the bandnames of 2 datasets:

```py
before = ee.Image(before).select([0])
after = ee.Image(after).select([0])
bef = ee.String(before.bandNames().get(0))
aft = ee.String(after.bandNames().get(0))
```

That I would like to use in a `ee.String`. At the moment I'm doing client side as such:

```py
bname = ee.String(f"change_from_{before.getInfo()}_to_{after.getInfo()}")
```

Is there a way to do it server side ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one don't want to use `cat` to keep the structure of the initial message humanly readable I propose the following solution:

```js
// write the string using the convention you like (I kept the one from python)
var string = ee.String("change_from_{}_to_{}")

// set the replacement string in a list 
var replacements = ee.List([
  before.bandNames().get(0),
  after.bandNames().get(0)
])

// iteratively replace the replacement character by the content of the list
var new_string = replacements.iterate(function(r, s){
  return ee.String(s).replace("{}", r)
}, string)

print(new_string)
```

I think the more parameter you have the more sense this method will have.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ee.String.cat()`:

```
var bname = ee.String('change_from_')
  .cat(before.bandNames().get(0))
  .cat('_to_')
  .cat(after.bandNames().get(0))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/46c3441c744dfaab64968b9d6c7b7611

**Update**

You could go down the route with a utility function to format a string based on named parameters:

```
function formatString(template, args) {
  return ee.String(template).match('{{.*?}}', 'g')
    .iterate(
      function (match, acc) {
        var key = ee.String(match)
          .replace('{{', '')
          .replace('}}', '')
        var replacement = ee.Dictionary(args).getString(key)
        return ee.String(acc).replace(match, replacement)
      },
      template
    )
}

var bname = formatString('change_from_{{before}}_to_{{after}}', {
  before: before.bandNames().get(0),
  after: after.bandNames().get(0)
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c4131245acdd615b5860686ac534b54e

Comment: My only concern with `cat` is that you loose the initial structure of the message. so if you have, let's say 12 parameters, it's barely possible to check what you are writing.